# How to write a Spring Data MongoDB query using Date manipulation

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to write a mongodb query using spring data repository @Query annotation and here is my requirement:

> **Get all the Vins that were added in the last sixty minutes and they are still active**

"keepAlive" is the time in milliseconds a particular VIN is active. When a record is entered in database, "keepAlive" can be set as 30 minutes, 60 minutes etc

Example data:

> ```
> { vin: "ANBCDERGGGHHGUTY", keepAlive: "3600000", dateAdded: "2019-12-16T16:45:29-05:00" }
> { vin: "T5765ERGGGHHGUTX", keepAlive: "1800000", dateAdded: "2019-11-14T13:41:29-03:00" }
> ```

Here are my classes:

```
public class MyEntity {
    private String vin;
    private long keepAlive;
    private Date dateAdded;
}
```

I have tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
@Query(value = "{'keepAlive':{$lte : {$subtract: [?0, 'dateAdded']}}}")
List<MyEntity> findLatestVins(Date currentSystemDate);
```

Any idea how can I do this?

Comment: a side note: 60000 ms is not 60 minutes, it's 1 minute.

Comment: Thank you, updated the times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the sample data `db.cars.find()`:

```
{ "vin" : 1, "keepAlive" : 3600000, "dateAdded" : "2019-12-17T15:00:29+01:00" }
{ "vin" : 2, "keepAlive" : 3600000, "dateAdded" : "2019-12-17T13:00:29+01:00" }
{ "vin" : 3, "keepAlive" : 1800000, "dateAdded" : "2019-12-17T15:00:29+01:00" }
```

please note that the field `keepAlive` is of type `number`

on the `mongodb` console:

```
db.cars.find({
    $expr: {
        $gte: [
            "$keepAlive", 
            { 
                $subtract: [
                    new Date(), 
                    {$toDate: "$dateAdded"}
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
})
```

**version 3.2 compatible** (using aggregation pipeline):

> db.collection.aggregate( [ {  }, ... ] )

```
> db.cars.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            vin: 1, 
            keepAlive:1, 
            dateAdded:1, 
            notExpired: {
                $gte:[
                    "$keepAlive",
                    { 
                        $subtract:[
                            new Date(),
                            { $toDate:"$dateAdded" }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $match: { notExpired: true }
    },
    {
        $project: { notExpired: 0 }
    }
])
```

Comment: Hey man, that's excellent, it works like a charm. Some questions: when do we use `$expr`?

Comment: while solving, I started along the same line as you did, using the `$gte` inside the `find`. But the syntax of `$gte` is `{field: {$gte: value} }`, that means we have to provide a *value*  for comparison and not an *expression*. Therefore the `subtract` expression did not work for you. Inside an `$expr` block,  arguments can be any valid aggregation expression and so is `$subtract`.

Comment: Hey Sudipn, it turns out our mongo version 3.2 doesn't support "$expr", is there a mongo version 3 compatible query we can use.

Comment: added a 3.2v compatible answer. have a look